# Adding selected listview items to a Global array

Tags: c#, visual-studio, win-universal-app

Context: I am creating a program in UWP with a menu that has an object array with 3 different arguments or attributes. The menu orders a food from a listview. I created an add button that would add the selecteditem to a global array so that I can transfer it to another page. The issue I've run into is that I've created a for loop to add the item for the add item button and it just spits out the last item I selected 20 times on the next page. I'm fairly novice and learning so please excuse me if I am using a very backward out of the way method to get my results, but I am just figuring this all out as I go along. Anyway here is the code for the loop, maybe its obvious I just need a new set of eyes.

```
 private void AddItemButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        for (int i =0;i<20;i++)
        {
            GlobalVars.GlobalStringArray[i] = (ListView.SelectedItem.ToString());

        }

    }
```

And a little added context, heres the next page.

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            ListResultView.Items.Add(GlobalVars.GlobalStringArray[i]);
        }

    }
```

Sample Data from array that's loaded into listview for selection

```
        MenuItem[] newItems = new MenuItem[20];
        newItems[0] = new MenuItem("Breakfast", "Bacon and Eggs", 5.00);
        newItems[1] = new MenuItem("Breakfast", "Pancakes", 4.25);
```

Comment: `ListView.SelectedItem` doesn't change inside the loop.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. Why the "20" in your loop? Why do you add only the SelectedItem (Which like St.Pat said doesn't change). Got some example data for us?

Comment: Yeah I'm new to Listviews and I didn't know it didn't change. I want to take the selection the user made from the list view of the items ive populated it with and store that in an array so that I can make a list of them on the next page in a checkout page. The 20 is the size of the array and I just had it there because i couldnt get array.length the compile. Theres 20 items in the array from what they select from thats why I put it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all selected items in ListView and save them into a global variable, you did not need to add a specific button to do it.

The [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview) control has `IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled` and `SelectionMode` to enable multi-selection. After that, you could register `SelectionChanged` event to get all selected items like the following:

```xml
<ListView IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
        <ListViewItem>item1</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>item2</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>item3</ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

```cs
List<string> ls = new List<string>();
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
    {
        ls.Add((item as ListViewItem).Content.ToString());
    }

    foreach (var _item in e.RemovedItems)
    {
        ls.Remove((_item as ListViewItem).Content.ToString());
    }  
}
```

Then, if you navigate to other page, you could pass this list as parameter.

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1),ls);
```

You could get this list on other page:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if (e.Parameter != null)
    {
        List<string> ls = e.Parameter as List<string>;
        foreach (var item in ls)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a simple code sample for your reference, in your case, you would need to do changing by yourself.